# Cannot access database on SQL Server via my VPN

Tags: sql-server, vpn

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I need to access the database using a VPN. I have no issue logging on the SQL Server using my VPN but I can't expand the database or query it.

When I click the database to expand it, I get the following message:

```
The database XXXX is not accessible. (ObjectExplorer)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.DatabaseNavigableItem.get_CanGetChildren()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItem.RequestChildren(IGetChildrenRequest request)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.ExplorerHierarchyNode.BuildChildren(WaitHandle quitEvent)
```

If I query a table from the database, I get the following message:

```
Msg 916, Level 14, State 1, Line 2
The server principal "Bi" is not able to access the database "HMS_ARL" under the current security context.
```

Any kind of help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Seems you don't have permission to open that database. Unless you logged on as a different user than you would when not using the VPN, then it seems unlikely that the VPN is related. It's a permissions issue within SQL Server.

Comment: Can you RDP into that SQL server and run the same query via SSMS?

Comment: (in case you don't get an answer, here is some discussion which might relate to your issue) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391673/determining-the-current-security-checks-being-made-sql-server